# How to block a request which does not has a header using Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lambda, amazon-api-gateway

My application back-end was laid on AWS Lambda and exposing API's using API Gateway. And forntend on CloudFront. I want to block a request which does not has a header using AWS service. Can anyone suggest me which AWS service will helpful to do this and what is the process?

Comment: Check the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524973/is-there-any-way-to-identify-requests-coming-to-custom-origin-server-from-cloudf/42635450#42635450 I think it's your answer.

Comment: @GayathriK do you mean to say block a request that does not have a *specific* header?  Which header?